# calling elements of an array one by one in a sql query as a part of ruby on rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a ruby code which has sql query calling the array but i am not sure why its not giving me the required result.

I am trying to alter each users resource pool with the sql query and i am not sure if its calling the array correctly in the sql query.

```
user_names = ["Dominic-Behl", "Emma-Smith", "Monica-Seth"]

user_names.each do |user_name| 
   # to change the default resource_pool of the user
   query_db(db_conn, "GRANT USAGE ON RESOURCE POOL vip_pool TO \"#{user_name}\"")
   query_db(db_conn, "ALTER USER \"#{user_name}\" RESOURCE POOL vip_pool")
end
```

Comment: Have you checked if your DB user (used by the application) has privileges to do this kind of command?

Comment: @gabrielpedepera yes, because its working for other straight forward queries where its not calling any array and has just a user_name.

Comment: Did you get an error when you were running the queries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what the user_name value is coming out as on each iteration. Can you print out user_name in the block and see what you get?

```
user_names.each do |user_name|
  p user_name
```

I would also try doing this with a regular for loop.

The other thing you could also try is change:

```
query_db(db_conn, "GRANT USAGE ON RESOURCE POOL vip_pool TO \"#{user_name}\"")
query_db(db_conn, "ALTER USER \"#{user_name}\" RESOURCE POOL vip_pool")
```

to:

```
query_db(db_conn, "GRANT USAGE ON RESOURCE POOL vip_pool TO '#{user_name}'")
query_db(db_conn, "ALTER USER '#{user_name}' RESOURCE POOL vip_pool")
```